# python-pip-whl installation is failing in kali linux

Tags: package-management, kali-linux

I am new to linux admin activities and not that familiar with terminology. I need to install python-pip. But, it has dependency on python-pip-whl (20.1.1-2 ) which is already installed but not recognized.

```
root@kali:/home/kali# apt-get install python-pip  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.4) but 20.1.1-2 is to be installed  
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed  
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I installed python-pip-whl (20.1.1-2 ). But, i think, existence of older versiosn of python-pip-whl is causing the problem. How to handle this situation.

```
root@kali:/home/kali# apt-get install python-pip-whl  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
python-pip-whl is already the newest version (20.1.1-2).  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
  dcraw flac libaudio2 libopenal-data libopenal1 libout123-0 libportaudio2 libsndio7.0 mpg123 openjdk-8-jre python-backports.functools-lru-cache  
  python-bs4 python-dnspython python-html5lib python-lxml python-netaddr python-soupsieve python-webencodings sqlite3  
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 463 not upgraded.


root@kali:/home/kali# apt list -a python-pip-whl  
Listing... Done
python-pip-whl/kali-rolling,now 20.1.1-2 all [installed]  
python-pip-whl/bionic-security,bionic-updates 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.4 all  
python-pip-whl/bionic 9.0.1-2 all
```

Comment: "I am new to linux admin activities [...]" In that case, Kali Linux is not the right choice for you. Do yourself a favor and pick a different distribution. Read https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: The line `Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.4) but 20.1.1-2 is to be installed` shows that the package requires the version specified (9.0.1-2.3) and the newer version (20.1.1-2) does not satisfy the dependency.  The tag is Kali Linux, but these are Ubuntu packages, which may not be compatible.

Comment: @GracefulRestart, thank you for the response. python-pip-whl is already installed. when i try to do the install of python-pip-whl, it tell me that, python-pip-whl version 20.1.1-2 is already installed on the machine.

Comment: Thank you @panki!! I am following a  tutorial. here the problem is, there are mutliple versions of python-pip-whl and latest version of python-pip-whl is not being recognized by apt while upgrading python-pip. I am tyring to find the setting which needs to tweaked.

Comment: I have downloaded the pip and did the installation using the steps    --                          curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py; python get-pip.py